Epson SDK not giving error codes when unable to connect to printer, I'm using Angular Nativescript
Is there a way of getting error codes from printer.connect using epson ePOS SDK?
All I'm getting is "Error: com.epson.epos2.Epos2Exception", with no apparent way of investigating the error further. Below is the code to connect to the printer, printer initialization works fine, the issue is when attempting to connect.
Initialise printer
 initializePrinter() {
        try {
          // Replace `TM_T20` with your specific printer model and `MODEL_ANK` with language
          this.printer = new com.epson.epos2.printer.Printer(
            com.epson.epos2.printer.Printer.TM_T88, // Adjust to your model
            com.epson.epos2.printer.Printer.MODEL_ANK,
            null
          );
          console.log('Printer initialized');
          this.showAlert('Printer initialized')
         
            this.connecttoPrinter();
            } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error initializing printer:", error);
            this.showAlert('Error initializing printer')
            }
      }

Connect to printer
  connecttoPrinter() {
        try {
             this.printer.connect("TCP:192.168.0.115", this.printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
            console.log('Connected to printer');
            this.showAlert('Connected to printer')
            this.printSampleText();
            }
            catch (error) {
                if (error instanceof com.epson.epos2.Epos2Exception) {
                    console.error("Epos Error connecting to printer:", error.getErrorStatus());
                    this.showAlert('Epos Error connecting to printer '+ error.getErrorStatus())
                }else{
                    console.log("Error connecting to printer:="+ error);
                    this.showAlert('Error connecting to printer '+ error);
                   
                }
            }
      }


what is this.printer and what is error

The error "Error: com.epson.epos2.Epos2Exception", this.printer is a printer instance defined globally. I've edited my question to include printer initilisation.

this doesn't provide any useful information. What data type does this.printer have and what type does error have? any kind of docs reference?

this.printer is of type any, error is just a catch clause, couldn't find much on documentation.

I would suggest you to try and figure out the documentation. I don't think I could help you out, since I haven't worked with epson

@T.Jami, thanks for your help, I had to use a java helper to get the printer to work on Nativescript. Documentation only references Java. Thanks again.

Looks like constructor is ip, port, callback... the callback receives the response from the API which may be an error.  See here: https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/epos_js/ref_epos_sdk_js_en_eposdeviceobject_connectmethod.html#i893740
